# Google Places API Places Types

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

[image]
The above picture is result of search nearby in web browser.
That doesn't shown in my application using google map using nearby places.

Does google map(from web) and google map api for android has different type of places?
Like for example I searched for veterinary clinic using web browser,
the result is different from the result in android.

```
&types=veterinary_care|pet_store|veterinary_clinic|veterinary|animal_clinic|animal_hospital|veterinarian|animal_shelter
```

That's my parameter for types in getting nearby places using android.
Well, the result is different from web.
Example this place.
[Map Link](https://www.google.com.ph/maps/place/Animal+Shelter+Veterinary+Clinic/@14.5688443,121.0828333,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3397c7d95815b1f3:0x974d8b779702668a)
when i searched nearby places, this will be marked in web browser using google map.
but when i used my google map in my application.
Its not marked.

Comment: Mean, there should be any mark?

Comment: Theres some marked places using those parameters, but the given link which is near in my place doens't have mark

Comment: Mean, which type of mark, can you specify?

Comment: Mark, marker in map.

Comment: Didn't got it, can post some image, related to this?

Comment: sure. I edited my post

Comment: So, you are saying about marker?

Comment: No. I'm saying that, the result from google map from browser is different from the result in my application's google map

Comment: Ok, So in your mobile what is coming?

Comment: In mobile. that place(Look in the image) is not marked in my map., Which is supposed to be marked.

Comment: It will return the result, but it will not put a marker. You need to do that after getting plcaes `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: My app is putting the markers already, Its working now. my problem is, that some certain places is not marked.

Comment: which is supposed to be marked.

Comment: Nothing will be marked, we need to add markers to the map.

Comment: You don't get me. My marker is working. Just certain places is not marked.

Comment: Like, can you mark anything, and show, which is not displaying?

Comment: I am able to mark places. yes anythng. except that in image

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API do support `veterinary_care` and `pet_store` but not the other parameters you have passed.

See the list of types supported in Google Places API [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Comment: yes, im just guessing that type of parameters since the one in the given link is not marked in my map

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, You are able to see some places on the maps.google.com whereas, you are not able to see the same with the Client libraries that Google provides.

If this is the case, yes its true that there are certain places that are updated on the live Google Maps but one cannot get them from the Client libraries (either Web or Android) that Google provides.

Similar questions have been raised on SO before too.

Comment: Would there be any fix to this? is there a way to view those unmarked places in my map(android)